# What defines angles in more general Banach spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, banach-spaces

In Euclidean spaces, we have these extra polar/shperical/cylindrical coordinate systems that sometimes make dynamic or trigonometric problems easier to study. I'm wondering if there is an analog of these polar coordinates for more general Banach spaces. Would this be an inner product space that defines angles between objects? If $x$ is an element of a complete inner product space, could someone go through an example of how they'd represent it in polar coordinates?

Comment: You can define angles given an inner product, so in a Hilbert space. But in a general Banach space there's no inner product available.

Comment: Okay, so it's an inner product that defines angles, thanks.